# ERROR in Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app (error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I create a react app ,and i'm facing this issue, i try to refresh and it
fades away, but when i refresh the page again ,the error pop-up

Comment: [Did you try searching for a solution?](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=ERROR+in+Plugin+%22react%22+was+conflicted+between+%22package.json+%C2%BB+eslint-config-react-app+%28error%29&cat=web&pl=ext-ff&language=english&extVersion=1.3.0)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.